# Spring-Boot application fails to start after changes in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following configuration in my application.properties file

```
#database-configurations
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exam
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#jpa-configurations
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

But the application fails to start with these configurations. It was working fine before. It so happened that I deleted the configurations in application.properties file by mistake and started the spring-boot app. It failed to start because obviously there were no configuration in application.properties. The error stated that datasource URL could not be found. But now even when I enter all the details correctly in the application.properties file I still get the same error. It seems it is not reading the values from application.properties file. It got stuck with the configurations settings that I deleted from application.properties.

Im getting the following error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-01-22T14:55:32.603+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m152247[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Spring Tool Suit added the following lines in META-INF folder in 'additional-spring-configuration-metadata' file.

```
{"properties": [{
  "name": "spring.datasource.driver-class",
  "type": "java.lang.String",
  "description": "A description for 'spring.datasource.driver-class'"
}]}
```

Following is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.exam</groupId>
    <artifactId>examserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>examserver</name>
    <description>backend code for exam portal</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you tell us what the error message is

Comment: I have edited the question to include the error that Im getting. Thanks for your reply

Comment: How does your pom look like?

Comment: Edited my question to include the pom. Thansk for your reply. :-)

Comment: No problem. Did you place the application.properties under src/main/resources?

Comment: Yes, it is under src/main/resources. I think this might be some kind of bug, maybe. As it was working fine with the same configurations before.

Comment: Replace spring.datasource.driver-class by spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver . Does that work? When I start that it works without a problem and states that connection refused because I don't have any mySQL database running locally

Comment: I tried with [ spring.datasource.driver-class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ] , [spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver], [spring.datasource.driver-class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] and with [spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but noting seems to work

Comment: I added a working version of your project [here](https://gitlab.com/samuel1998.schwanzer/stackoverflow-question.git). Does this start at your end? If yes it must be something else than pom and application.properties.

Comment: your problem in this line `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exam
` I suggest to check profile enabled if you have a profile and check if the database is exist using sqlWorkbanch or any equivalent tools

Comment: if you know your db is ok and running then try deleting the .idea file the target file and unlink your maven module and recompile it again.

Answer (score -1):

The application.properties file must be located in src/main/resources folder.

Comment: It is under src/main/resources

Comment: This is not an answer!